# Merging data frames such that Time column remains unique in R

Tags: r, merge

> Hello,  I am trying to merge these two data frames such that there's
>   only one unique time column and an additional column called TYPE is
>   created which is attributed to PK (TYPE==1)  or PD (TYPE==2) for their
>   respective times. I have never done something like this before, any
>   help would be highly appreciated.

```
    temptime<-c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
    tempconc<-c(0:6)
    PK<-cbind(temptime,tempconc)
    temppdtime<-c(0,2,5,7,9)
   temppd<-c(100:104)
   PD<-cbind(temppdtime,temppd)
   PKPD<-merge(PK,PD)
   PKPD
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of how you want your expected output to look like?

Comment: If you show us your expected output , we may help you out

Comment: ####Expected Output 

Etype<-rep(1:2, times=7)
length(Etype)
EDV<-c(0,100,1,101,2,102,3,103,4,104,NA,105,NA,106)
length(EDV)
ETime<-c(0,0,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,7,9)
length(ETime)
Eoutput<-data.frame(Etype,EDV,ETime)
head(Eoutput)

Answer (score 1):

Rename your time variables to be the same in both PK and PD. Then create the TYPE variable in each PK and PD, filled out with 1 or 2 for the respective dataframe. Then rbind PK and PD.

Comment: Does not work. Just tired it. The problem is time is not sorted in increasing order.

Comment: temptime<-c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
tempconc<-c(0:6)
PK<-data.frame(temptime,tempconc)
PK$Type<-rep(1,times=length(PK$Conc))
names(PK)
library(plyr)
PK<-rename(PK, c("Conc"="DV"))
temppdtime<-c(0,2,5,7,9)
temppd<-c(100:104)
PD<-data.frame(temppdtime,temppd)
PD<-rename(PD, c("PD"="DV"))
PD$Type<-rep(2,times=length(PD$PD))
PKPD<-rbind(PK,PD)
PKPD

Comment: Why does time need to be sorted in increasing order?

Comment: This is the expected output>>>>>>> Etype<-rep(1:2, times=7)
length(Etype)
EDV<-c(0,100,1,101,2,102,3,103,4,104,NA,105,NA,106)
length(EDV)
ETime<-c(0,0,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,7,9)
length(ETime)
Eoutput<-data.frame(Etype,EDV,ETime)
head(Eoutput)

Comment: The time needs to be sorted in increasing or as this data will be used to run some simulations in NONMEM which would need the time to be in increasing order.

Comment: Just sort your dataframe by time then after you've merged everything

Comment: PKPD
newdata <- PKPD[order(PKPD$Time),] 
This works. But its there any other way which is more efficient? This needed a lot of changes. And the data frame here is pretty small, but how do we do it more efficiently when we have large data frames ? Thanks.

Comment: How do you want it to be more efficient? It's basically 3 non-complex steps: 1) define an id variable for each dataframe, 2) merge dataframes, and 3) sort new dataframe by desired variable.

Comment: I will get back to you on this. for now I'll just use this method. But im sure there are packages in R which can help do this kind of stuff. Thanks for the inputs mate. Appreciate it.